# ImageView visibility problem with device rotation

Tags: java, android

When device rotate, I want to set visibility of ImageView.
I dont know difference of following two example.
I wonder if onConfigurationChanged cannot work or if there are other problems.

1) normal code

>

```
package com.facebookexam.www.facebookexam;    
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView iv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.MainLogoIV);
    updateLayout(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    updateLayout(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}

private void updateLayout(boolean isLandscape) {
    if (isLandscape) {
        iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

}
```

2. abnormal code

package com.facebookexam.www.facebookexam;

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView iv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.MainLogoIV);
        iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing “abnormal” here.

In first instance, you are making ImageView gone if orientation is Landscape. [if(...)]

In second instance you are making ImageView gone in all orientation. [No conditional operation].